# Group by sum for multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have multiple documents with same `studId` and `month` for 300 students.

Inside every document it's having array called `marks` as follows:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("575953d49b315b14249e8bf4"),     
    "studID" : "1369", 
    "month" : "2016-1",        
    "marks" : [ 
        { 
            "subType": "Optional",
            "marks": 30 
        },         
        {
            "subType": "Optional"  , 
            "marks": 35
        }, 
        {
            "subType": "compulsory", 
            "marks": 30  
        },        
        {
            "subType": "Optional", 
            "marks": 35 
        }  
     ]
},  

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575953d49b315b14249abcfr"),
    "studID" : "1369",
    "month" : "2016-2",
    "marks" : [         
        {
            "subType": "Optional", 
            "marks": 30 
        }, 
        { 
            "subType": "Optional", 
            "marks": 35 
        }, 
        { 
            "subType": "compulsory", 
            "marks": 30 
        },          
        { 
            "subType": "Optional"  , 
            "marks": 35
        } 
    ]
}
```

I want to find `month wise total marks` for optional and compulsory subject.

Result should be:

```
"studID" : "1369":
"month" : "2016-1"
"subType":"Optional","optional toatal":100
"subType":"compulsory" "compulsorytoatal":30

"month" : "2016-2"
"subType":"Optional","optional toatal":100
"subType":"compulsory" "compulsorytoatal":30
```

I have tried the following query:-

```
db.calculatedmarks.aggregate([
     {$match:{ "studID" : "1369" }}, 
     {$unwind: "$marks"}, 
     {$match:{ "marks.subType":'compulsory' }},
     {$group:{ _id:null, total:{ $sum:"$marks.marks" } }} 
])
```

but it gives all months total marks for `subtype compulsory`.

Comment: What you have tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: db.calculatedmarks.aggregate([
    {$match:{
         "studID" : "1369"
    }},
    {$unwind: "$marks"},
    {$match:{
        "marks.subType":'compulsory'
    }},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        total:{  
            $sum:"$marks.marks"
        }
    }}
])   it gives me total of  compulsory sub marks for all months . I want separate for each month

Comment: Can you add the query in your question?

Comment: yes...edited in a question

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what kind of output you want. You may want to read more about the `$group` operator in the MongoDB manuals. Remember, `$group` uses the `_id` attribute for grouping, so if you set `_id` to a constant value like `null` you'll get exactly one row back. Here's something you could try:

```
db.calculatedmarks.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$marks" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { studID: "$studID", month:"$month", subType:"$marks.subType" },
            total: {$sum: "$marks.marks"}
        }
    }            
])
```

to obtain this output:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "studID" : "1369",
        "month" : "2016-1",
        "subType" : "Optional"
    },
    "total" : 100
}
```

Append this to the pipeline:

```
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: { studID: "$_id.studID", month:"$_id.month" },
            subType: {$push: {subType: "$_id.subType", total:"$total"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.studID",
            month: {$push: {month: "$_id.month", subType: "$subType"}}
        }
    }
```

to get an output similar to this:

```
{
    "_id" : "1369",
    "month" : [ 
        {
            "month" : "2016-1",
            "subType" : [ 
                {
                    "subType" : "Optional",
                    "total" : 100
                }, 
                {
                    "subType" : "compulsory",
                    "total" : 30
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: How to sort result by month in above query??

Comment: @learner: Add a $sort stage, something like `{$sort: {"_id.month": 1}}`. Keep in mind that if `month` is a string, it is sorted as a string – `"2016-11"` comes before `"2016-2"`. It’s a good idea to format months always with two numbers, like `"2016-01"` which mitigates the sorting problem.